# Preposition with 'unbecoming.'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning

What is the difference between various prepositions used with **unbecoming**?
E.g,
***unbecoming to*** vs ***unbecoming for*** vs ***unbecoming of***.
And sometimes when there is no preposition at all, like *conduct **unbecoming** an officer*.

Answer (score 2):

It's an adjective, and depending on what's being described, different prepositions will be appropriate. Merriam-Webster dictionary specifically includes a preposition for "conduct unbecoming to an officer". [Unbecoming](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbecoming)